# how to copy composer install modules of vendor from one project to another project magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.3, third-party-module, magento2-enterprise, vendor, composer-update

> Is it possible copy composer install modules of vendor from one
> project to another project magento 2 without composer commands.
>
> If anyone having any idea please guide. I knew that it's not good
> practice but i don't have more ideas on it.

Comment: when we install module using composer, it added entry in composer.json and composer.lock. So you need to copy those entry as well.

Comment: @Pawan, yes i copied entries in both composer.json, composer.lock and app/etc/config.php file  but after upgrade it's removing entries from app/etc/config.php

Comment: upgrade means module upgrade or setup:upgrade ?

Comment: yes setup:upgrade

Comment: what happens if you do not make entry in config.php and run setup:upgrade, it should automatic add entry in this.

Comment: yes i knew it but even it should add entry in config.php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112875/discussion-between-hitesh-balpande-and-pawan).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the contents of the composer.json file from the old project and to the new one. Then run

`'composer install'`

It will then install all dependancies into the vendor folder.

Comment: yes i did same but for me paid  extension entry was not downloaded. so i removed that entry and did  used 'composer install' command.

Comment: Why don't you move this paid module that won't install via composer from the vendor folder to the app/code folder of the new site? If you take a look at the etc/module.xml file you'll see the <module name="Namespace_Module"> xml node. You then match this in your folder structure.  So it becomes app/code/Namespace/Module then the contents of the vendor folder for that module inside.